# React CSS Keyframes - animate when state removes component from DOM

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm struggling to use CSS Keyframes with React.

I can get them to work when the component is mounted but when the component is unmounted the CSS transitions don't get a chance to animate before the state removes it from the DOM.

I'm not keen on doing this with a JS library when it feels like there should be a way to do this with good old CSS.

I've got a codepen that I put together to show what I've got so far.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-forked-dhvu7?file=/src/styles.css

At the end of the animation I'd like the component to be unmounted I don't want it to stay in the dom.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should first **add some class** that *signals the CSS* it should **trigger an animation**, and from there you have some options: use `setTimeout` in your react code and then actually remove the element, or use some other clever way to know when the animation is finished and then remove the element

Comment: From your code it looks like you do not need a CSS `animation` but a simple `transition`. simply add a class with the desired CSS outcome and set a `transition` property on the element, so when the class appears, it will transition to those properties defined on the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css [keyframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) and use [onAnimationEnd](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) event handler to trigger state change after the animation is finished. Also you can add `style={{ animationFillMode: "forwards" }}` to the node to preserve the CSS properties of the last keyframe before removing it from the DOM.

Example:

```
{removeDom && (<button
      style={{ animationFillMode: "forwards" }}
      className="some animation class"
      onAnimationEnd={()=>setRemoveDom(true)}
 />)}
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone else wanting a solution this article got me to where I wanted to be
https://czaplinski.io/blog/super-easy-animation-with-react-hooks/